# A weird www showing before my server name on page load

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Im working on a local server for development. Im using a ubuntu with apache2 installed.
My website is developed with codeigniter framework.

When I try to access this url: https://svr-wr/sendit/caja/login/
I got this on my console:

[image]

When I press CTRL+U to se the source code I have this:

[image]

I use the `base_url()` helper for codeigniter with this value:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/sendit/';
```

Doing an echo of this return this `value: https://svr-wr/sendit/`

And also have an .htaccess file in order to avoid the index.php of my framework,
the htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Well, thats all I dont know why there is a "www" before my server name, any suggestions?

Comment: Try echo / printing the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, does that contain www. ? might be an apache setting?

Comment: Can you use stackoverflow to host the images in case those links break, or better yet copy the code into your question?

Comment: Echo $SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] return: svr-wr

Comment: Does this problem happen in all browsers or just Chrome? Try testing other browsers and see if it's a browser specific issue.

Comment: tested in other browsers and other pcs too.

Comment: But why are the addresses in the second screen shot correct? Are you loading things twice perhaps?

Comment: Check what you have in header template file. see whether you have `public/admin/` in it. Header should be probably in folder `/views/templates` or directly in `/views` folder

Comment: @Pacio I'm not loading twice, I just show how is coded in the html vs how it try to load.

Comment: I'm thinking about the apache2 config files, could it be?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, both of those images show messages created by the browser, in other words they're both html. One shows calls to correct urls, and one doesn't. If both of those come from the same page you must be making 2 calls, one to a url with www and one without.

Comment: @Pacio yes im showing the redered html from the browser. I ensure you that is not a double call. https://snag.gy/BhjsAo.jpg

Comment: solved. inside my folder svr-wr/public/admin there was an .htaccess file with a redirect rule forcing "https://www." thanks everyone for the help :) <3